# How can I use charlexproxy's map local to model a response which consists of an image file and json using map local

Tags: json, charles-proxy

Charles proxy question.

I need to model a response from an API call using map local.  I've done this before, but in this case the API is both returning an image, as well as JSON.

Is it as simple as creating two map local functions for the same call, one returning the required image, the other the required json?

If not, what's the best way of doing this, if it's possible at all that is?

Comment: How does an API "both returning an image, as well as JSON"? What kind of `Content-Type` would that be?